# Post route for register

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Not doing my handleSubmit function right. Would appreciate any input. I think I am close. I think this is the reason it is not working. I am just trying to get a post request to work for a registration page. State.username or password doesnt seem to be working. I tried this.state.username and it was undefined. Not sure what I am missing.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { TextField, Button, Typography, Paper } from '@material-ui/core';
import useStyles from './styles.css';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';

const Auth = () => {

    const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const divStyle = {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
      };

     const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const user = {
          username: state.username,
          password: state.password,

        }
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/auth', { user })
          .then(res=>{
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);
          })
      }

    return (
        <div style = {divStyle}>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <h1>Registration</h1>
            <TextField 
                name='username' 
                variant='outlined' 
                label='username' 
                fullWidth 
                
                onChange={(e) => { 
                    setUsername( e.target.value)
                }}
             />
             <TextField 
                name='password' 
                variant='outlined' 
                label='password' 
                fullWidth 
                
                onChange={(e) => { 
                    setPassword( e.target.value)
                }}
             />
             <Button variant="container" color="primary" size="large" type="submit" fullwidth>Register</Button>
            </form>
        </div>
      );
}
 
export default Auth;
```

Comment: Hey Sean, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I did. The answer was right then I had some other problems and worked through it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sean, change your handleSubmit function by taking out the "state" in front of the username and password variables.

```
     const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const user = {
          username: username,
          password: password,

        }
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/auth', { user })
          .then(res=>{
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);
          })
      }
```

You might have to put a value property on your `<TextField>` components as well. In that case you would do `value={username}` and `value={password}`